# How to use restrict option with other languages

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4, restrict, flashplayer-10

How can I use restrict option of the TextField class with other languages?

For example for english is simple

```
var tf:TextField = new TextField();
tf.restrict = "A-Z a-z 0-9 ? . , ; ";
```

How can I use it to enable to add just basic punctuation characters for example for hebrew or for so cyrilic languages taht use UTF-8 encoding?

is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the \u escape sequence to construct restrict strings. The following code includes only the characters from ASCII 32 (space) to ASCII 126 (tilde).

```
 my_txt.restrict = "\u0020-\u007E";
```

[source](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6#restrict)

Comment: I tried this but still when I change the system locale to some cyrilic lang for example, I cannot write those charaters. It still need to be en_US in order to work.

Answer (score 0):

as an example: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyrillic_script_in_Unicode)
"Cyrillic' U+0400 – U+04FF (256 characters) or just "Basic Cyrillic" U+0410 - U+044F. 
That can save a few minutes :)